# Azure SDK: the product cannot be installed because a product that it depends on did not install successfully

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net, web-platform-installer

I'm trying to install Microsoft Azure SDK for .NET (VS 2015) - 2.8.2.1 through Web Platform Installer.

Full error:

> The product cannot be installed because a product that it depends on did not install successfully

[Logs](http://pastebin.com/xdAvTjvr)

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to install all those packages manually (without Web Platform Installer).

For 2.8.2 version you can download it [from this site](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50041). For other versions go [here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/search/result.aspx?q=Azure%20sdk&form=MSHOME) (in "Downloads" category).